# Setting up Team System Load Test Agent correctly on a workgroup

Tags: testing, tfs, load-testing

I'm trying to start a load test on a rig. I've got three computers :

- Computer 1: Visual Studio Team System Test Edition
- Computer 2: Controller
- Computer 3: Agent

The computers are part of a workgroup (not on a domain), the controller indicates that the agent is ready for testing. My problem is that when I try to run a test (from C1), it gets stuck in pending mode forever.

Can anyony advise on how to solve that ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a special installation when set up a load test in a workgroup.

All informations can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh546459.aspx#workgroup)

Also, follow the [Troubleshooting Guide](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vststest/thread/df043823-ffcf-46a4-9e47-1c4b8854ca13) and activate trace file.

For futures references, the good news is that it is nearly the same for VS 2008/2010/2012.